# How to plot a control and a treatment groups in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

`dput (Data)` is, as follows:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001), RwandaGDP = c(266296395453522, 
266232388162044, 278209717380819, 278108075482628, 271435453185924, 
264610535380715, 280150385073342, 257433853555685, 128078318071279, 
173019272512077, 195267342948145, 222311386633263, 242005217615319, 
252537014428159, 273676681432581, 296896832706772), ChadGDP = c(221078469390513, 
215510570376333, 248876690715831, 261033657789193, 250126438514823, 
271475073131674, 293196997307684, 247136226809204, 272188148422562, 
275553889112468, 282165595568286, 297579071872462, 318265518859647, 
316009224207253, 313311638596115, 349837931311225), RwandaLifeExpectancy = c(50.233, 
47.409, 43.361, 38.439, 33.413, 29.248, 26.691, 26.172, 27.738, 
31.037, 35.38, 39.838, 43.686, 46.639, 48.649, 49.936), ChadLifeExpectancy = c(46.397, 
46.601, 46.772, 46.91, 47.019, 47.108, 47.187, 47.265, 47.345, 
47.426, 47.498, 47.559, 47.61, 47.657, 47.713, 47.789)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), RwandaGDP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ChadGDP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), RwandaLifeExpectancy = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ChadLifeExpectancy = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ";"), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001f0ef568410>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I come from performing a Difference in Differences regression in R, with the following code:

```
GDP <- as.numeric(Data$RwandaGDP, Data$ChadGDP)

MyDataTime <- ifelse(Data$Year >= "1994", 1, 0)

MyDataTreated <- Data$RwandaLifeExpectancy

MyDataDiD <- MyDataTime * MyDataTreated

DidReg = lm(GDP ~ MyDataTime + MyDataTreated + MyDataDiD, data = Data)

summary(DidReg)
```

Now, there is only one thing left to do, which is to plot the results.

I am looking for something akin to what can be seen in point 3.4 (line plot) on this website:

https://rpubs.com/phle/r_tutorial_difference_in_differences

However, when I try to adapt my code to the one that is facilitated on the aforementioned website, I keep getting the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

I've been stuck with this issue for hours, and I really don't know what I am doing wrong in my code.

Any help would be enormously appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

My adapted code is, as follows:

```
Data %>%
  mutate(label = if_else(Year == "1994", as.character(GDP), NA_character_)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Data$Year,y=Data$RwandaGDP, group=GDP)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=GDP), size=1.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = "Rwandan Genocide", linetype="dotted", 
             color = "black", size=1.1) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Accent") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(17,24)) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label = label),
                   nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = -0.5,
                   na.rm = TRUE) +
  guides(scale="none") +
  labs(x="", y="GDP") +
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = "1994",
    y = "",
    label = "{Difference-in-Differences}",
    angle = 90,
    size = 3
  )
```

Comment: Can you show your code for how you "adapted your code" and attempted your plot?

Comment: Hello, @stomper! Thank you for your response! I have just included my "adapted code" in the edit of the question. For which I get the aforementioned error, i.e., "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `scale_colour_continuous(palette = "Accent")` to `scale_colour_continuous(type = "gradient")`

I also removed your `scale_y_continous`. Unsure rationale behind this code.

added `pivot_longer`

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("RwandaGDP","ChadGDP"), names_to = "country", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year),
         label = if_else(Year == "1994", as.character(value), NA_character_)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=value,col=country)) +
  geom_line(size=1.2) +
  # scale_color_continuous(type = "gradient") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1994, linetype="dotted", 
             color = "black", size=1.1) +
  # scale_color_discrete(palette = "Accent") +
  # scale_y_continuous(limits = c(17,24)) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label = label),
                   nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = -0.5,
                   na.rm = TRUE) +
  guides(scale="none") +
  labs(x="", y="GDP") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 1994,
    y = median(GDP),
    label = "Difference-in-Differences",
    angle = 90,
    size = 3
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @KKW, many thanks for your help! The only thing is that, with this code, you have plotted only Rwanda GDP; while I also need to have Chad GDP on the same graph for comparison. Do you know, by chance, how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one geom but will need to approach your labels differently.  If you have more than one country you are looking to display, consider putting your data in a long format with tidyr::pivot_longer.

```
Data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Year)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=ChadGDP, color=GDP), size=1.2) +
    geom_line(aes(y=RwandaGDP, color=GDP), size=1.2)+
    scale_color_continuous(type = "gradient") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1994, linetype="dotted", 
               color = "black", size=1.1) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = Data[Data$Year == 1994,], aes(label = RwandaGDP, y = RwandaGDP),
                              nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = -0.5,
                              na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = Data[Data$Year == 1994,], aes(label = ChadGDP, y = ChadGDP),
                              nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = -0.5,
                              na.rm = TRUE) +
    guides(scale="none") +
    labs(x="", y="GDP") +
    annotate(
        "text",
        x = 1994,
        y = median(GDP),
        label = "{Difference-in-Differences}",
        angle = 90,
        size = 3
    )
```

[image]

Comment: agree that `pivot_longer` would do the trick too

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why you want to use a gradient color scale when you already have the GDP represented on the y-axis. Consider something like this.  This approach also sets you up to graph your other variables and multiple countries.

```
Rwanda <- Data %>%
    select(Year, LifeExpectancy = RwandaLifeExpectancy, GDP = RwandaGDP) %>%
    mutate(Country = "Rwanda")

Chad <- Data %>%
    select(Year, LifeExpectancy = ChadLifeExpectancy, GDP = ChadGDP) %>%
    mutate(Country = "Chad")


CountryData <- rbind(Rwanda, Chad) %>%
    mutate(`GDP(Trillions)` = round(GDP/1000000000000,2))


CountryData %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Year)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=`GDP(Trillions)`, group = Country, color = Country), size=1.2) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1994, linetype="dotted", 
               color = "black", size=1.1) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = CountryData[CountryData$Year == 1994,], aes(label = `GDP(Trillions)`, y = `GDP(Trillions)`),
                              nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = -0.5,
                              na.rm = TRUE) +
    guides(scale="none") +
    labs(x="", y="GDP (USD Trillions)") +
    annotate(
        "text",
        x = 1994,
        y = median(CountryData$`GDP(Trillions)`),
        label = "{Difference-in-Differences}",
        angle = 90,
        size = 3
    )
```

[image]